# Possible to copy-paste without markup in Org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, copy-paste, markup

You can add inline code and verbatim text in Org-mode using this syntax:

```
~<code>cd ~~</code>~

=verbatim /text/=
```

This is expected to display:

> <code>cd ~</code>
>
> verbatim /text/

If you copy the content in the Org-mode buffer and paste it into any other program, the content is pasted with the full markup.

**Is it possible to copy and paste only what is displayed and not the markup?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ASCII exporter if you customize the option `org-ascii-verbatim-format` to `%s`.
Export to a buffer and copy the code there.

The following command sets the options temporarily for you as needed and then exports directly into the kill-ring:

```el
(defun org+-copy-code ()
  "Export code silently to kill-ring."
  (interactive)
  (require 'ox-ascii)
  (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'org-element-normalize-string) #'identity))
    (save-excursion
      (kill-new
       (org-export-as 'ascii
              nil nil t
              '(:ascii-verbatim-format "%s" :ascii-paragraph-spacing auto :ascii-headline-spacing nil :preserve-breaks t))
       ))))
```

You can try that command after evaluating the code above by selecting the region you want to copy and <kbd>M-x</kbd> `org+-copy-code` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

If you like what you see you can copy the code to your init file and bind `org+-copy-code` to some key, e.g., <kbd>C-c c</kbd> by the following line in your init file.

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'org
    (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c c") #'org+-copy-code))
```

Comment: I had to add `:with-author nil` to the `org-ascii-export-as-ascii` options. But pasted text copied with this function has a trailing new line. How to get rid of it?

Comment: @lecodesportif It is better to use the `BODY-ONLY` option of `org-ascii-export-as-ascii`. I modified the code accordingly. Furthermore, I just cut off the final newline which comes from exporting the paragraph and section. Check whether you can live with that.

Comment: The new version removes all the new lines from copied non-empty lines, not just the final one. Ideally, ox would not add a final new line at all. I want to use a function like `org+-copy-copy-code` as my standard copy function and in that case I might also copy paste a text with a trailing new line (which should not be removed).

Comment: @lecodesportif The culprit was an unconditional `org-element-normalize-string` in `org-export-as`. I've neutralized it with `letf`. As I understand you `org-element-normalize-string` would be bad anywhere during code export.

Comment: The newline issue still remains. Try copying multiple a code block of multiple consecutive `~<code>cd ~~</code>~` lines with the function. For me they all paste on one line.

Comment: @lecodesportif Ah, yes. There is `:preserve-breaks` which I have set thru `org-export-preserve-breaks` in my init file. That is why I did not notice. Now, I have tested with `emacs -Q` and it should work.